# CSS3 Box-Shadow applying to content in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, box-shadow

Hi I was trying to apply a box shadow to my main content box but it doesn't work correctly in IE. Rather than applying the shadow to the edges of the box like in firefox & chrome it seems to apply shadw to the content.

here are the filters im using:

```
 /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=10, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=10, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
```

Comment: Can you give us the surrounding code - like the object you are applying the shadow to?

Comment: <div id="content"> <div id="contentcontainer" class="shadowbox"> <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" /> </div> </div>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using CSS3 PIE (http://css3pie.com) instead of filters. It offers a much more complete and accurate rendering of shadows that matches that of native-CSS3 browsers almost identically. It keeps your CSS cleaner too.